# I want to stream to my localhost

Tags: php, flash, video-streaming, localhost

I am using wamp server and in my project i want to stream to localhost and currently i'm using 
open broadcaster software and stream to twichtv. Then i have inserted the flash objects in my local web page. I want to know whether is there any way to this within the localhost itself. I used the vlc media player and it does not fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Stream to your localhost from where?

Comment: currently i want to stream from my computer it self. for example a screen capture or web cam video output.